# what is advantage of using list definition in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

Why do we need a list definition to create custom list in visual studio?
I can create a custom list using the UI without the need for visual studio.

So what is the advantage of using a list definition to create a custom list in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI can only create a list on a single server, in a single site. You can't copy this list to a different server, eg. to deploy it from your development machine to the production server.

It's also difficult to use the same list in different site collections or web applications. While you can save a list as a template, you can only use this template in the site collection it was created in.

The only way to define a list that you can easily deploy to multiple servers is by creating a list definition. Otherwise you'll have to backup and restore your entire site from one server to the other, or use third party tools that will do essentially the same thing.

Deploying using a list definition can take seconds. Deploying by backup/restore can actually take days, as SP will only warn you that something went wrong only AFTER the entire restore process has finished.

Furthermore, there are form customizations that can't be done without modifying the actual list definition, eg. hiding columns. If you create the list through the UI you'll have to use a third party tool to make the modifications.

Comment: When I save custom List as template in site collection you mentioned i cannot use this list in another site collection but after test it i discover it Possible to use template in different site collection؟

Comment: When I save custom List as template in site collection you mentioned i cannot use this list in another site collection but after test it i discover it Possible to use template in different site collection؟  @Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 0):

Would also add, when doing development, you will need a procedure to migrate your code from DEV ennvironment to Your UAT environmet and then onto Production envirnment

If you do this manually it will take some time, also there is always a risk you have not created it the same way.

using list definations will make sure it is the same on each environment